# Saving a redux state to localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage

I have a react crud app which uses redux, here's what the structure looks like. The data it uses is just a paragraph wrapped around div tags nothing complicated, what is a good way to store the data inside local storage

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to store the state and all the todos inside localstorage?

UPDATE:
after following the answer below, this is the error I get,
[image]
Here's how I configured it, this is the store.js file
[image]

Comment: why do you want to save in local-storage if you have redux?

Comment: I am loosing the data after refreshing the page.

Comment: Please provide the code as plain text instead of screenshots

Answer (score 4):

You should never do something like this in your reducer file as it needs to be a pure function. What you can do is subscribe to store like this in your store file.

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
  localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
})
```

To load it after every refresh you have to use something called persistent state.

```
const persistentState = localStorage.getItem('state') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) : {}
const store = createStore(reducer, persistentState)
```

Comment: Hey! I just noticed something odd, I followed the same steps you mentioned, it only works on chrome, not working on brave, Firefox and even edge

Comment: It should not be a problem. Any specific error?

Comment: Also can you check if the store.subscribe is getting triggered after state change.